# Clicking a button after locating it by its text (Python/Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium

So I'm writing a script that takes data from one page and searches for it on another and then once it finds a match, clicks a corresponding `"Transfer"` button.

On the second page I am able to locate the `"Transfer"` button I need using `xpath` siblings and searching for it by text, but once I find the text, how do I then click the button? Adding a `.click()` doesn't seem to do much (presumably because it's just clicking the text element). I should also note that this is my first time working with `xpath` axes and only my 3rd or 4th full script in general, so I'm definitely a beginner.

Here's the relevant code from the second page:

```
<div ng-repeat="junc in production.filteredJuncList = (production.juncList.Data | filter:searchJunc) track by $index" class="grid-row tableRow MyJunc ng-scope" id="33490336">
                            <div class="col-1"></div>
                            <div class="col-2 marketplaceInventoryText ng-binding">2</div>
                            <div class="col-3 marketplaceInventoryText ng-binding">406</div>
                            <div class="col-2 marketplaceInventoryText ng-binding">5</div>
                            <div class="col-6 marketplaceInventoryText">
                                <span ng-show="junc.Quantity === 1" class="ng-binding ng-hide">4</span><span ng-show="junc.Quantity > 1" class="ng-binding">4 - 5</span>&nbsp;
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-2" style="padding-left: 55px;">
                                <button class="btn ng-isolate-scope btn-primary" ng-class="{'btn-default': !(type) || (type === 'default'), 'btn-primary': (type === 'primary'), 'btn-success': (type === 'important'), 'btn-contrast': (type === 'contrast'), 'btn-outline': outline, 'btn-sm': !(size), 'btn-lg': (size === 'large')}" ng-transclude="" data-type="primary" data-size="small" ng-click="openInitiateDrawer(junc, production.details)" style="min-width: 53px;"><span class="ng-scope">Transfer</span></button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
```

And here's how I've located the button (the `"406"` and `"5"` are the data I've scraped from the first page, using that I'm locating the corresponding button):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[text()="406"]/following-sibling::div[text()="5"]/following-sibling::div[button[span[text()="Transfer"]]]')
```

Edit: So far I was able to find a workaround by reverse engineering the xpath for the Transfer button. It requires the "id" for the entire row which can be found in the outerHTML of the parent element. Using get_attribute and paring down the HTML to just the id#, I'm able to store it as a variable and pass it to an xpath. A little less elegant, but works for now.

Comment: Can you check if this transfer button is inside any ```frame```. Search for frame in the DOM

Comment: could you share a screenshot of ui or of the html dom which contains transfer button

Comment: @afaalgo Here is a screenshot of the UI: https://ibb.co/GxZ5twS

Comment: @afaalgo the button doesn't seem to be inside any frame.

Comment: can you inspect the Transfer button for that row and update the HTML DOM

Comment: @afaalgo I can but, the Transfer button is already located in the code above. The line where it says "<button class=..." is what you see when you inspect the transfer button.

Comment: did you try writing like this ```div/button/span[text()="Transfer"]```

Comment: Yes and with that I can locate the button, but for some reason when I add .click() to the end, nothing happens.

Comment: maybe you should get parent of `span` and click `<button>` instead of clicking `<span>`?

Comment: I see button has `ng-click="openInitiateDrawer(junc, production.details)"` which should execute JavaScript code when you click button - maybe you should use `driver.execute_script("openInitiateDrawer(junc, production.details)")` to execute this function directly - without clicking.

Comment: //div[text()="406"]/following-sibling::div[text()="5"]/following-sibling::div/button[./span[text()='Transfer']] this would be the fixed xpath since you need to click the button instead.